# Unused variable & path

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, variables

I keep banging my head on the keyboard... why do I get these warnings? :
 Unused variable '*'
 Unused variable 'path'

```
-(IBAction)pushGenerate {
NSString *title = nil;
NSString *path = nil;

static NSString* a[] = {        
    @"What do I want?",
    @"Who do I want?",
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not used these variables within that function.That's why it is displaying the warnings

Comment: Would apple deny the app because of these warnings ?

Comment: As far as my knowledge apple don't reject the App

Answer (score 1):

In `pushGenerate` you are creating a pointer to an address holding a string and setting it to nil but you aren't using it. At the end of `pushGenerate` this address is lost as the variable was local.

What are you trying to do?

Comment: It's a bit embarrassing being a newbie.. I've created an app that randomizes questions with a button click. Would apple deny the app because of these warnings ? [The app runs, they are just yellow warnings]  ps:i bow down and kiss your hand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would apple deny the app because of these warnings ?

Comment: No, but you should try to figure out what the problem is here. This will increase your knowledge about development.